# What is the fastest way of saving big csv files into azure database using bulk insert from sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, bulkinsert

I'm trying to download a big file from FTP and store it somewhere into some azure storage and then run BulkInsert in sql on azure and save data into a table

I have an FTP server that I read data as CSV files from. Some of those files are very heavy about 1.5GB or even more. So far, I have been downloading these files into memory and then save them to the database using C# BulkCopy on azure but now I'm getting this error OutOfMemoryException which seems to be due to the size of the file.

That's why I'm thinking about using BulkInsert directly from SQL on azure but then that SQL instance needs access to the storage that the file is downloaded to and of course it cannot be my local machine because it seems like I can not run BulkInsert command on SQL Server on Azure when the source file is located on my local storage.

Is there any way of download and save a file into Azure storage that SQL has access to and then execute BulkInsert?

Comment: Using `SqlBulkCopy` class from C#, See [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: See Also Post About Bulk & Azure : [Can I Use SqlBulkCopy With Azure SQL-PaaS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706540/can-i-use-sqlbulkcopy-with-azure-sql-paas)

Comment: @JonathanLarouche  I DON'T want to save data from memory I want to insert data from a file which is stored on the hard drive (storage on Azure)

Comment: If you are reading from Azure Blob, then you can read this: [Bulk Insert Azure Csv Into Azure Sql](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52061.t-sql-bulk-insert-azure-csv-blob-into-azure-sql-database.aspx)

Comment: Just use Azure Data Factory. ADF does use quite a lot of optimizations internally

Comment: I would use https://www.filehelpers.net/ , and implement an IDataReader that you can feed directly into the SqlBulkCopy class.

Comment: @JonathanLarouche Thanks the last comment included what I was looking for but now there is another problem that how can I download the file directly from FTP into that storage on azure?

Comment: For this, it better to ask another question

Answer (score 0):

You can using the Data Factory to copy the data from the FTP to Azure SQL.

Data factory has the better performance to transfer big data:
[image]

Data Factory support the FTP as connector.

[image]

Please reference these tutorials:

1. [Copy data from FTP server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp)
2. [Copy data to or from Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)
3. [Copy data from Azure Blob storage to a SQL database by using the
   Copy Data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool)

> How can I download the file directly from FTP into that storage on azure?

You use create a pipeline, using FTP as Source, Storage as linked server.

You can also copy a big file from FTP to Azure SQL directly.

Hope this helps.